# Data degradation process

Tags: sd-card

Studies have shown that data degradation for SD cards/micro SD cards start happening within a few months. I have a card that I haven't used for over a year, I had the SHA1 hash of the physical drive from over a year ago and compared it with the current drive and they are identical. meaning no data was lost.

1. As I understand it, single bit errors may be correctable by the built in controller, but that wouldn't be happening if the SD card isn't having power and just sitting on a shelf for over a year (my case).
2. the studies show that much larger data degradation happen after 12 months, but the SHA1 hashes are identical, meaning no data was lost at all with the SD cards being over a year on a shelf, how is that possible?

Comment: You're asking us to explain discrepancies between a study and your lived experience.  Can you share a link or links to the relevant study or studies?  My first thought is that the studies may be statistical in nature and represent hundreds or thousands of SD cards.  In this case you can have statistically significant data loss without implying anything about individual cards.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of your earlier closed question [Expected data loss, but no data loss?](https://superuser.com/questions/1642557/expected-data-loss-but-no-data-loss)

Comment: *"As I understand it, single bit errors may be correctable by the built in controller, but that wouldn't be happening if the SD card isn't having power..."* -- Your understanding is incorrect.  Error detection and correction uses additional bits to the actual data, aka **ECC** (Error Correction Code).  Depending on the number of ECC bits and algorithm used, the correction capability can be more than one bit.  *"Power"* is irrelevant.  The ECC is calculated when the data block is written.  Verification and correction (if possible) occurs on every read of the block.

Answer (score 1):

SD cards have a relatively short term reliability, they work by storing a charge on the floating gate of a special MOS transistor. The charge is switchable from 0 to 1 for the value. After a certain amount of time, the charge degrades and switches by itself, causing data degradation or "bit rot". In your case, you were lucky, your card must have been well built and stored in suitable temperatures, and none of the charges have degraded and switched in value. Most cards however, would have somewhat degraded in that amount of time.